# Fetching With Distinct/Unique Values

Tags: mapreduce, cloudant

I have a Cloudant database with objects that use the following format:

```
{
  "_id": "0ea1ac7d5ef28860abc7030444515c4c",
  "_rev": "1-362058dda0b8680a818b38e9c68c5389",
  "text": "text-data",
  "time-data": "1452988105",
  "time-text": "3:48 PM - 16 Jan 2016",
  "link": "http://url/to/website"
}
```

I want to fetch objects where the `text` attribute is distinct. There *will* be objects with duplicate `text` and I want Cloudant to handle removing them from a query.

How do I go about creating a MapReduce view that will do this for me? I'm completely new to MapReduce and I'm having difficulty understanding the relationship between the `map` and `reduce` functions. I tried tinkering with the built-in COUNT function and writing my own view, but they've failed catastrophically, haha.

Anyways, would it be easier to just delete the duplicates? If so, how do I do that?

While I'm trying to study this and find ELI5s, would anyone help me out? Thanks in advance! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure a MapReduce view is what you are looking for. A MapReduce view will essentially allow you to get the text and the number of docs with that same text, but you really won't be able to get the rest of the fields in the doc (because MapReduce has no idea which doc to return when multiple docs match the text). Here is a sample MapReduce view:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/textObjects",
  "views": {
    "by_text": {
      "map": "function (doc) { if (doc.text) { emit(doc.text, 1); }}",
      "reduce": "_count"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

What this is doing:

The Map part of the Map Reduce takes each doc and maps it into a doc that looks like this:

```
{"key":"text-data", "value":1}
```

So, if you had 7 docs, 2 where text="text-data" and 5 where text="other-text-data" the data would look like this:

```
{"key":"text-data", "value":1}
{"key":"text-data", "value":1}
{"key":"other-text-data", "value":1}
{"key":"other-text-data", "value":1}
{"key":"other-text-data", "value":1}
{"key":"other-text-data", "value":1}
{"key":"other-text-data", "value":1}
```

The reduce part of the MapReduce (`"reduce": "_count"`) groups the docs above by the key and returns the count:

```
{"key":"text-data","value":2},
{"key":"other-text-data","value":5}
```

You can query this view on your Cloudant instance:

```
https://<yourcloudantinstance>/<databasename>
/_design/textObjects
/_view/by_text?group=true
```

This will result in something similar to the following:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":"text-data","value":2},
  {"key":"other-text-data","value":5}
]}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, but rather you are just looking to keep the latest info for a specific text value then you can simply find an existing document that matches that text and update it with new values:

1. Add an index on `text`:

   ```
   {
      "index": {
         "fields": [
            "text"
         ]
      },
      "type": "json"
   }
   ```
2. Whenever you add a new document find the document with that same exact `text`:

   ```
   {
      "selector": {
         "text": "text-value"
      },
      "fields": [
         "_id",
         "text"
      ]
   }
   ```
3. If it exists update it. If not then insert a new document.

Finally, if you want to keep multiple docs with the same text value, but just want to be able to query the latest you could do something like this:

1. Add a property called `latest` or similar to your docs.
2. Add an index on `text` and `latest`:

   ```
   {
      "index": {
         "fields": [
            "text",
            "latest"
         ]
      },
      "type": "json"
   }
   ```
3. Whenever you add a new document find the document with that same exact `text` where `latest == true`:

   ```
   {
      "selector": {
         "text": "text-value",
         "latest" : true
      },
      "fields": [
         "_id",
         "text",
         "latest"
      ]
   }
   ```
4. Set `latest = false` on the existing document (if one exists)
5. Insert the new document with `latest = true`

This query will find the latest doc for all text values:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "text": {"$gt":null}
      "latest" : true
   },
   "fields": [
      "_id",
      "text",
      "latest"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go with finding an existing document that matches that text and update it with new values.